# Using app's identity (Azure AD) in ASP.NET web app to call Microsoft Graph

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My ASP.NET MVC web application is currently using on-premise SMTP server to send mails.

To understand, here is the classic scenario:

- Users have to sign-in in the web app with a user/password (encrypted and stored in SQL DB)
- Users fill in a form
- When form is posted 2 mails are sent (one for the user and one for the team)

We have to migrate to an Azure VM (Virtual Machine) based solution. I am asked to use **Microsoft Graph** to send mails as a replacement of using SMTP server. I found a lot of documentation and tutorials on this subject. The classic solution asks the user to sign in using Open ID Connect and Azure AD is used for the authentication (MSAL). So a new authentication page is showed to the user where he should authorise the application to perform specific actions like sending mails (for example). See picture below.

[image]

In my situation, I prefer not force user to authenticate a second time. As explained in scenario above users already sign in with (basic) user/password not related to Azure AD.

So I thought I would use app's identity in place of user's identity. This way the user should not authenticate a second time. I found a quickstart on the Microsoft's website which seems to fit my needs.

Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon

Obviously I thought to integrate this concept in my ASP.NET web app and not in a console app but you get the idea.

**So I would like to know if the solution of using app's identity in place of user's identity (authentication in Azure AD) to send mails in my ASP.NET web app is a good approach.**

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is feasible.

In fact, Microsoft does not recommend users to log in to applications based on username/password, which requires a very high level of trust in the application and may bring certain risks.

In your question, you want to use the application to act as its own entity instead of performing operations on behalf of a specific user, so as to avoid repeated login authorization for users. I think this is a good method, but you have to pay attention, if you need to use the application's own identity request token to access MS graph api, then you must grant `application permissions` to the application, and then use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) as the authentication flow.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at the client credential flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a VM you could enable managed identity and avoid dealing with credentials. Take a look to this [article](https://winsmarts.com/managed-identity-as-a-daemon-accessing-microsoft-graph-8d1bf87582b1).

Comment: Thanks. Your link does not work but I was able to perform a search on Google.

Comment: @Bronzato corrected the link. Hope I can get an upvote now :)